# Console frozen on server but I have full access to the server and I can ssh in

Tags: linux, centos7

I have a Linux server running CentOS7. I am able to ssh in, run commands etc. It's running a number of services such as apache, mysql etc. When I go to the console it's showing services that were started and some logs from syslog. Nothing else seems to work (e.g. ALT + f2). If I ssh in in the server and use `w` it shows the only session there being my SSH session. How do I kill the process that controls the main terminal on the server?

Comment: Do you have a desktop environment installed (e.g. GNOME, KDE, etc...)? Does the issue persist after a reboot?

Comment: Could you check dmesg if anything gets loaded? Maybe a graphics module causes a console hang? Have you been able to verify keyboard working during bootup or similar?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall the exact setting but there was a video card setting was enabled in BIOS. As soon as I disabled it, everything started working as expected.